What’s the difference between fftshift(fft2(fftshift(x))) and fftshift(fft2(x))?
I’m coding in MATLAB, and I need to get the correct spectrum of an 2d array x(like what continuous Fourier transform does).
I’ve tried the following two ways.
fftshift(fft2(x));
fftshift(fft2(fftshift(x)));

It seems that both give the correct intensity distribution of x’s spectrum, I wonder which one gives the correct spectrum of x。
Thank you very much for your help!

The difference will only be in the phase. You are shifting in the time domain, which implies a phase change in the frequency domain. If you look at the magnitude of the spectrum, it doesn’t matter. If you care about the phase, then you need to make sure that the origin of your time-domain data is in the first sample (x(1)). For some applications this matters, for some it doesn’t.

fftshift is an operation on spectra, not on the state space. do not apply it to x. its purpose is to make some processing simpler (e.g. masking a circular area in the spectrum).

Thank you guys, in this case I really care about the phase, I think I’ll check the math.

As Christoph Rackwitz points out, fftshift is meant as a utility function to operate on sequences in the frequency domain, and is not intended to operate on signals in the time/space domain.
fftshift is often handy when operating on 2d image information in the frequency domain (e.g. edge detection). However, this is not often needed in the case of time domain processing (at least this true in my experience).
A picture is worth a thousand words. For ease of visualization, this is a 1D case:

Code:
t = 0:1/512:1;                
x = chirp(t,0,1,10);
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x);
hold;
plot(fftshift(x));
legend('x', 'fftshift x');
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(abs(fft(x)));
hold; 
plot(fftshift(abs(fft(x))));
legend('abs(fft(x))', 'fftshift(abs(fft(x)))');


The DFT doesn't define negative frequencies. The frequency k runs from 0 to N-1. There is periodicity, so that k=N-1 is the same as k=-1, but things are so much simpler if you forget about that and just think of k=0..N-1.

@CrisLuengo, that is an interesting point. The definition of DFT does indeed run from 0 to N-1, but the Nyquist theorem suggests that the frequencies under analysis are in the range of -N/2+1 to N/2-1. Also (anecdotal, to be sure) I have often heard people talk about the top half of the spectrum as the 'negative frequencies'.

I've updated to the post to remove confusion about periodicity in the FFT and thinking in terms of negative frequencies. Hopefully still useful to the OP.

Yeah, for sure, lots of people refer to the top half as the negative frequencies. And this is not wrong. I just think things are easier to understand if you don't. The frequencies in the DFT above Nyquist alias to lower frequencies, so it's weird that you need them, but the math says that you do. And after applying fftshift, those components are to the left of 0, so now it makes sense to assign them negative frequencies. I don't think of fftshift moving the negative frequencies to the left, but as shifting the window over the periodic frequency domain from 0..N-1 to -N//2..(N-1)//2.
